# Any way to simulate a mouse click (or anything else) and select an option within a dropdown on a webpage that I do not own?

Tags: html, iframe, click

I'm displaying a webpage within an iframe.  It contains an option to click a dropdown and defaults to Full Results.  The other options (depending on the size of the tournament) are:

- Winner's Bracket
- Loser's Bracket
- Top 128
- Top 64
- Top 32
- Top 16
- Top 8

I'm looking for a way to do this since there isn't an option to do this within the embed code.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Link to sample page: https://challonge.com/20210602/module?selected-round-filter=2&show_final_results=0&multiplier=2&show_tournament_name=1&scale_to_fit=1

Including a screenshot in case the link ever dies:

[image: Print Screen]

And the area of the page's source code that contains the dropdown values in case that is helpful:

```
<div class='container-fluid -with-header-gutters bracket-controls-wrapper'>
<div class='bracket-controls'>
<span class='live-stamp hide'>
<span class='tip' data-container='body' data-placement='bottom' title='This bracket updates in real-time.'>
<div class='dot'></div>
Live
</span>
</span>
<div class='pull-right'><div class='dropdown'><a class='selected-round-filter' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
Full Bracket</a>
<ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right round-filters'>
<li>
<a href='#'>Full Bracket</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-rounds='1,2,3,4,5' href='#'>Winners Bracket</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-rounds='-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6' href='#'>Losers Bracket</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-rounds='3,4,5,-3,-4,-5,-6' href='#'>Top 8</a>
</li>
</ul></div></div>

</div>
</div>
<div class='tournament-bracket-wrapper'>
<div class='full-screen-target'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch a `click` event with [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

In the example below, we look for the option that reads 'Winners Bracket', then execute a click event on that option. This selects the 'Winners Bracket' option in the `<select>`.

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right.round-filters li a');
var lookFor = "WINNERS BRACKET";
options.forEach((e) => {
    let option = e.innerHTML;
    if (option.toUpperCase() == lookFor) {
        e.click();
    }
})
```